# How do I rewrite this function to reduced form

Tags: trigonometry

$$f(t) = e^{-t} (2 \cos (2 t)-\sin (2 t))$$

I wonder if it's possible to rewrite this as

$$f(t) = g(t)\cos(\alpha t + \theta),\quad g(t)>0$$

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt 5$. Now write $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ as $\ sin a$, the other one as cos and use coscos - sin sin

Comment: It worked. How did you know about this relationship? $\arccos\frac{2}{\sqrt 5} = \arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ Or actually I might be confused.

Comment: When you have acos - bsin multiply and divide by root of a square plus b square. So then you can call a upon that as cos and b upon that as sin. They obey the trig identity.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, but there's just something missing. What do you mean by I can "call $a$ upon that as cos"?

Comment: $\frac{a}{\sqrt(a^2 + b^2)} = \cos \theta$

Comment: Is there any proof out there for this? I'm not sure what I should google to find this.